# mount sysfs with write permissions on unpriviliged docker container

Tags: docker, docker-container, sysfs

when running `docker run -v /sys:/sys:rw $NAME $COMMAND` , the container tries to write to a file in `/sys`, but this causes a "Permission denied" error.
The container user is root. In host, root has write permission to the files.
this issue is fixed with `--privileged`, but that option has serious security drawbacks.
how can a container have write access to sysfs without using `--privileged`?
I tried adding all the security capabilities with `--cap-add`, but it wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Docker runs /sys filesystem in read-only mode. In the docker forum was said that another container runtime named Sysbox can help, but I didn't try it.

https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-mount-sys-inside-the-container-with-rw-access-in-unprivileged-mode/97043